# Building a function iterating over a column

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to build a function to calculate CLV based on 3 inputs M,r,t, where M is a data frame of values, and r and t are constant.

M looks like this:
[image]

The code for the function I have is:

```
CLV_cohort <- function (M,r,t){
  CLV <- c()
  for (i in 0:t){
    for (n in names(M)){
      CLV[i+1] <-  mean(M$n)/((1+r)^i) 
    }
  }
  return(sum(CLV))
}

CLV_cohort(M,.10,9)
```

But I get an NA as a result.

The function is supposed to take the mean of each column, and divide by 1+r to the t power for the range 0:t or 9, then sum the results.

For example the function should simulate:

```
> mean(M$revenue_0)/((1+.10)^0) + mean(M$revenue_1)/((1+.10)^1) + mean(M$revenue_2)/((1+.10)^2) + mean(M$revenue_3)/((1+.10)^3) + mean(M$revenue_4)/((1+.10)^4) + mean(M$revenue_5)/((1+.10)^5) + mean(M$revenue_6)/((1+.10)^6) + mean(M$revenue_7)/((1+.10)^7) + mean(M$revenue_8)/((1+.10)^8) + mean(M$revenue_9)/((1+.10)^9) 
[1] 213.3541
```

I think I am iterating through the columns correctly but I still get an NA for my function

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `M[[i+1]]`, e.g.,

```
CLV_cohort <- function (M,r,t){
  CLV <- c()
  for (i in 0:t){
    CLV[i+1] <-  mean(M[[i+1]])/((1+r)^i) 
  }
  return(sum(CLV))
}
```

Comment: That seems to work @ThomasIsCoding but I think my tabs or function is off cause its calculating wrong. It's only calculating the mean of the last column and not of each column.